# Enable up to 5 SPI on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, spi

I'm trying to enable all the SPI Ports on my raspberry pi 4 (as mentioned in the [datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/rpi_DATA_2711_1p0_preliminary.pdf)).

I already enable the SPI interfaces over the raspi-config tool but that only gives me `spi0.0` and `spi0.1` when i check `/sys/bus/spi/devices`.

I found [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=246792#p1576629) where someone edited the config.txt to get the SPI's (somewhat) enabled. Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a way of doing this using C or Python? Is it it even possible to run 5 SPI in parallel?

Is there better documentation than the short datasheet?

I'm running raspbian with an RT Kernel Patch.

Update:
I was able to `spi0.0  spi0.1  spi1.0  spi2.0  spi3.0` by putting in /boot/config.txt

```
dtoverlay=spi0-cs
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs
dtoverlay=spi2-1cs
dtoverlay=spi3-1cs
dtoverlay=spi4-1cs
```

however spi-4 doesn't work, it's just not enabled

Comment: `boot.txt`? That's not a Raspbian file. What OS do you run?

Comment: I stand corrected, it says config.txt, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Julian, Welcome and nice to meet you. Yes, you can setup 5 SPI buses: 0.0, 0.1, 1.0, 1,1, 1,2: Your might like to read my lab report for more details: https://penzu.com/public/926a24f6.

Comment: My apologies for not reading the question carefully. Mine is only 2 SPI buses.

Comment: I am sorry that I mixed up five I2C buses with five SPI buses. Some time ago I read the following discussion about multiple SPI buses, but I have not tried. My apologies again: 
Raspberry Pi 4, enable multiple SPI busses
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=246792.

Comment: @tlfong01 thats the link I have in the question :)

Comment: Ah, same link, my apologies again. :)

Comment: Just now I inserted the alt function pin chart to my penzu file above. It is annoying to see there are so many conflicting alt functions. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to enable 4 SPI as according to the Forum Post. Enabling SPI0 or SPI1 together with 3-6 doesn't work. Heres my complete /boot/config.txt

```
#dtoverlay=spi1-1cs
#dtoverlay=spi2-1cs
dtoverlay=spi3-1cs
dtoverlay=spi4-1cs
dtoverlay=spi5-1cs
dtoverlay=spi6-1cs
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the second CS line for SPI0 since the second CS line of SPI0 shares the same GPIO with the SCLK of SPI4. To disable it, you need to make a copy of original device tree overlay in [GitHub source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.4.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/spi0-cs-overlay.dts) and remove the second CS line and then compile it using `dtc` command. Don't forget activating the overlay in `/boot/config.txt` instead of `spi=on`.

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
 
 
/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
 
        fragment@0 {
                target = <&amp;spi0_cs_pins>;
                frag0: __overlay__ {
                        brcm,pins = <8>;
                };
        };
 
        fragment@1 {
                target = <&amp;spi0>;
                frag1: __overlay__ {
                        cs-gpios = <&amp;gpio 8 1>;
                        status = "okay";
                };
        };
 
        __overrides__ {
                cs0_pin  = <&amp;frag0>,"brcm,pins:0",
                           <&amp;frag1>,"cs-gpios:4";
        };
};
```

```
# compile
dtc -I dts -O dtb -o spi0-1cs.dtbo spi0-1cs.dts
# copy to boot partition
sudo cp spi0-1cs.dtbo /boot/overlays
```

```
#dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi0-1cs
```

Comment: You seem to be linking to your own web site. Please add disclosure in accordance with the [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)

Comment: @tripleee the link to my own web site is removed